# Axios error: "write EPROTO 80E0330002000000:error:0A000152:SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled"

Tags: node.js, ssl, npm, axios

I'm trying to build an automation tool and hit the below url using axios.

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import https from 'https'
const crypto = await import('node:crypto');

const AxPortal = Axios.create({
  withCredentials: true,
  timeout: 100 * 1000, // 100 Seconds
  headers: {
    'Accept': `*/*`,
    'Accept-Encoding': `gzip, deflate, br`,
  },
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    keepAlive: true,
    // secureOptions: crypto.constants.SSL_OP_LEGACY_SERVER_CONNECT,
  }),
});

try {

  let config = {
    method: 'post',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: 'https://ahmedabadcity.gov.in/AMCWEBMODULE/PTAX/FrmTENE_PEC_Details.aspx',
    headers: {
      "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
      "accept-language": "en-GB,en;q=0.9",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "sec-ch-ua": "\"Not/A)Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"115\", \"Chromium\";v=\"115\"",
      "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
      "sec-ch-ua-platform": "\"macOS\"",
      "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
      "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
      "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
      "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
      "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1",
      "cookie": "IC=New_Portal-114; IC=New_Portal-114; ASP.NET_SessionId=intkr2s1fq3boisbk5euosub",
      "Referer": "https://ahmedabadcity.gov.in/AMCWEBMODULE/PTAX/FrmTENE_PEC_Details.aspx",
      "Referrer-Policy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
    },
    data: '__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24btnSearch&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUJOTM1NDc5NjAxD2QWAmYPDxYCHgxDaGVja1JlZnJlc2hkZGRkznBbvMGAVh0thuYS8qDrIRZGx59bhzOCypMaMhwHS%2F0%3D&__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR=866B1294&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAqzVdjcSZ6LdZ39M8DiBIgWTISMQzzysGHOJKfvpBax745MW6XMaFjzT9nUdsIknovSEwfOn6alsRzJy8wv1jf1vPli9vWGCGOvCtfFF2dKevXg5240PLXNY%2BeR7zMctTxlkr0BlKlqSn8ZtGvyeRqI2qFniAsD%2BUGyUd6UqbTrDXu2p7I4HFdVOythwxBf%2BZRXBDNB8ZAvxIUtf6ibcdVA%2BSKvH%2BHLvolUAqGprZxKRQZTFGJ8JvyTsrRcq2IwfLo%3D&ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24txtSEARCHNO=01020711500001V'
  };

  const resp = await AxPortal.request(config)

  console.log(resp.data)

} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

The error i'm encountering is "SSL routines:final_renegotiate:unsafe legacy renegotiation disabled"

If I add secure options, the request is successful, but the output html data is not as expected.

If anyone wants to try how the api works and what should be the actual response
visit 
URL -> https://ahmedabadcity.gov.in/AMCWEBMODULE/PTAX/FrmTENE_PEC_Details.aspx

and Enter tenement No `01020711500001V`

Comment: The problem of the error message is solved by the duplicate question and also what you yourself proposed. The problem that you did not get the expected output HTML is unrelated to this. For this create a new question with information of what you expected and what you got instead.

Comment: Created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76834813/axios-output-is-not-as-expected-when-using-secureoptions